# How do i use r-linux interface to recover files to USB drive?

Tags: data-recovery, usb-drive

I, very stupidly, did a shift-delete on some very important files on my /home partition and now I am trying to recover them.

I have been able to find them using r-linux, and it seems like they are still there and okay, however when I go to recover them it pops up with "Using the same drive as file destination is not recommended. Click Cancel to abort or Save to continue at your own risk"

I have a USB stick that is formatted as etx4 and i am trying to recover them to that, but i can't work out how to access it using the r-linux interface. I tried saving the files to `/media/<user>/<USB stick label>`  but it still pops up with the "using the same drive...." message.

I have also tried manually putting /dev/sdb1 as the path for the output folder for the files, but that still pops up the same message.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can do to access the USB stick through r-linux? I think i might be able to recover the files okay using that, but I just dont know how to use the interface to access the USB drive. Or alternatively, should i just ignore the message and save it to `/media/<user>/<USB stick label>`?

This folder contains all of the work I have done on my PhD for the last 3 weeks since my last backup and I am starting to get very worried!

Comment: I don't know anything about recovery, but I backup such important data *daily* in the cloud, even for semi-important term papers and such. So for the future: Write a little script that packs, i you want encrypts and uploads your important files in a minute and run it every day when you're finished.  Combine this approach with *git* and you never lose anything any more.

Comment: Normally i do much more regular backups, however i have just been doing some different work to usual the past month and my stuff has been all over the place and i havent had the opportunity to organise it all properly yet. Ironically, i was preparing to do that when i accidentally deleted everything..

Comment: Souns like Murphy's law, I'm sorry for you – maybe have a look at `debugfs` from the `e2fsprogs` package.

Comment: … and `foremost`!

Comment: I think that r-linux will work, i just cant seem to work out how the interface works so that i can choose the USB drive as the partition that i want to restore the files to..

Comment: I cannot post this as an answer, because your question explicitly talks about R-Linux, but... you can use Testdisk to undelete them. There is also `extundelete` that you can run as well. However it's very important that you run the tools from a live DVD/USB, not from your OS!